# Balance returns zero but shows ether with web3.eth.getBalance on testrpc

Tags: solidity, web3js, balances, command-line

**Issue:** 
Using an account on testrpc I get 0 as my balance from within a program but I get the correct amount when I query balance at web3 command prompt:

//here I'm calling a function (shown below) from command line

> contractInstance.queryBalance("**0xf24qf4b3ae667a23f296f48eb92fa619310c95fd**")
>   { [String: **'0'**] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
>
> //here's I'm listing my accounts, just showing the first one to save space
>
> web3.eth.accounts
>   [ '**0xf24qf4b3ae667a23f296f48eb92fa619310c95fd**',
>    ...

//here I am querying the balance directly at the command prompt

> web3.eth.getBalance('**0xf24qf4b3ae667a23f296f48eb92fa619310c95fd**')
>   { [String: '**99999999999984495002**'] s: 1, e: 19, c: [ 999999, 99999984495002 ] }

Here is the function call I'm making in my program:

```
function queryBalance(address addr) public constant returns (uint balance) {
    return balances[addr];
    }
```

**What else I've tried**
contractInstance.queryBalance("0xf24qf4b3ae667a23f296f48eb92fa619310c95fd", {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4500000})
{ [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
and

**Environment**: 
web3.js environment on Mac with testrpc running

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that `web3.eth.getBalance` returns the balance in ethers of your address.

But in your function

```
function queryBalance(address addr) public constant returns (uint balance) {
    return balances[addr];
}
```

You are returning the value you have stored in the balances mapping. If you didn't store anything the default value is zero.

To obtain the balance in ether of your address in solidity

```
function queryBalance(address addr) public constant returns (uint balance) {
    return addr.balance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear response. That's what I was looking for.